# compiling Vim 7.4 under AIX 6.1

Tags: c, regex, vim, aix

I have a problem while compiling Vim 7.4 under AIX 6.1. 
My options for the configure script are: "--prefix /opt/freeware/bin" and "--enable-pythoninterp".

There where no Errors while running the configure Script but when I try to run "make" I get the error message:

> cd src && make first
>   cc -qlanglvl=extc89 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_ATHENA -DFUNCPROTO=15     -g -o objects/regexp.o regexp.c "regexp_nfa.c"
>   line 4410.1: 1506-046 (S) Syntax error. 
>   make: 1254-004 > The error code from the last command is
>   1.
>
> Stop. make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.
>
> Stop.

Does anyone know what to do?
I had compiled Vim 7.4 in my home directory so I know that there is a workaround but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Your message  is a little chaotic.

Answer (score 0):

AIX's built in make (based on standard AT&T make) is not compatible with the Makefiles built by autoconf tools.   Use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (gmake) instead.   You may already have it installed (check /opt/freeware/bin), install from the Linux Toolbox for AIX set (from IBM), or from one of the websites providing prebuilt GNU tools for AIX systems (perzl, bullfreeware, etc).   Just provide an alias from make to gmake, or override the use of make in the Makefile itself.